# Apache2 and rewritemap - hours of trying

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, rewrite

I stuck with rewritemap problem.

What I want to do is redirect thousands of old nearly random urls to new ones. I will build map manually, but I need this code to work.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}\?%{QUERY_STRING} (^example\.com.abcd.cat_4)(.*)
RewriteRule .* ${url_rewrite_map:$1|NOTFOUND}? [R=301,L]
```

I would like map to look like this:

```
example.com/abcd/cat_4 http://example.com/345_exact_address_of_page
```

Old urls look like:

> http://example.com/abcd/cat_4=0?Xi4B7WoN;;54

and I want them to rewrite into:

> http://example.com/345_exact_address_of_page

I tried lots of things, but I cant get it working... Can you help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I got it working. For anyone else, here's the solution.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}\?%{QUERY_STRING} (^example\.com.abcd.abcd=.*)
RewriteRule .* ${url_rewrite_map:%1|$1}? [R=301,L]
```

To respond to Krist van Besien answer: I believe you cannot use %1%2%3 as using one line before, two lines before, etc. %n refers only to last RewriteCond line, so I had to put everything into one line and then make check of map. But thank you anyway, you pushed me into good direction :)

Answer (score 1):

You are using $1 as a lookup key in your map, but that parameter just holds what you capture in the RewriteRule. Strings you capture in your RewriteCond are captured in %1, %2 etc...

So you should use something along the lines of:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   (^example\.com)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/abcd/cat_4)
RewriteRule .* ${url_rewrite_map:%1%2|NOTFOUND} [R=301,L]
```